# ARMv7-M: What happens when a instruction loads a malformed address to PC

Tags: arm, cortex-m

I get a usage fault when a function returns using a pop to PC.
Interestingly, the PC that gets stacked is not the POP instruction but it's some other memory location (SRAM address, instead of a flash address).

When an instruction loads to PC and if the address doesn't have 0th bit set, would the load instruction complete and take the usage fault (so the stacked PC will be the target address) or the load instruction itself will fault (stacked PC will be the load instruction) ?

Comment: Have you checked the ARMv7-M Architecture Reference Manual (document ARM DDI 0403E.d) ?

Comment: To be fair the document is misleading.

Comment: @Michael I didn't find anything related to this in ARMv7 ARM.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried a simple test

```
mov r0, 0x140000
push {r0}
pop {pc}
```

The stacked PC is 0x140000. So it looks like the target gets stacked.

Comment: If the question is does the processor perform the instruction asked.  Yes it does.  If you do a push it will.....push that thing on the stack.   If you tell it to do a pop, it will do that too, whatever the data values...

Comment: then why dont/didnt you also try it with the lsbit set?